# Why do I have this weird colored static in my animation for a test stinger transition?

Tags: animation, 2d

[image]

When rendering it shows the animation as it should look. when I play it back in vlc  media player or some player I found on the Microsoft store it shows this weird static.

Comment: its a transition for streams its a 2d animation Just from some planes with keyframes. it only appears when I play the file back and not when Its rendering.

Comment: im using ffmpeg video codec 1 and eevee

Comment: It looks like a corrupt file, or an error in decoding. so let's try this again,  what codec are you using? (ffmpeg is not a codec). And what app are you using for playback? does it happen in a different app

Comment: Im using vlc media player also how do I check the video codec? I'm not sure if its corrupt file because I have tried rendering it multiple times, relaunching the program, my pc, and as I said moving objects in case it was the planes being on the same y level that was causing a rendering issue. As the video is rendering I see it play through it fine but when I open it in vlc it shows that. Is there a way I could send you the project .blend file?

Comment: Have you tried playing in a different app? What happens when you open the rendered video file in blender?

Comment: I tried it in some video player I found on the microsoft store and had the same issue, how would I launch it in blender?

Comment: im trying to use webm right now

Comment: use the Video Sequence Editor,

Comment: I used webm and it worked fine but when I used ffmpeg video codec it did the static do you know why it might have done that?

Comment: Again, ffmpeg is not a codec. It is possible that your video is using a codec that VLC cannot decode correctly that is why It is important to evaluate in different tools. But you can try to change the container and codec used to render into something that will play correctly with the app of your choosing.

Comment: Im not sure about that because it plays a few seconds of the animation then cuts to the static. Also how do I check my video codec?

Comment: The codec is in the output section, once you select ffmpeg (the set of tools to encode video) it shows Container and Codec.